# Java 2D Array index swap

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, indexing, sudoku

I'm currently working on a Sudoku Project and I'm very close to completion but I'm having an issue with a part of my code (Sorry the variable names are in French) where the line and column index of a 2D array have been exchanged somehow and I can't seem to find where this comes from. Here is the Array declaration:

```
int[][]sdkGrid = {
            {5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0},
            {6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0},
            {0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0},
            {8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3},
            {4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1},
            {7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6},
            {0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0},
            {0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5},
            {0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9}};
```

And here is the code where the two index are being swapped somehow:
The problem is I have no idea where the two index are being swapped.

```
public class FenetreGrille extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public final int [][] NOMBRES_DEBUT;
public int [][] GRILLE_MODIF = new int[9][9];
public int [][] GRILLE_FINALE = new int[9][9];

public final int TAILLE = 9;                                    //Mettre maj sur taille etc car ce sont des constantes  
public final int TAILLECASE;
public final int COTEGRILLE ;

public Grille1 Sdk;

public JPanel Container1;
public JPanel Container2;
public JPanel containermain;

public JTextField [][] cases= new  JTextField [9][9];
public JLabel FOND_ECRAN;
public JButton test = new JButton("test");


public FenetreGrille(int [][] NOMBRES_DEBUT){

    this.TAILLECASE = 60;
    this.NOMBRES_DEBUT = NOMBRES_DEBUT;
    this.GRILLE_MODIF = NOMBRES_DEBUT;
    Sdk = new Grille1(NOMBRES_DEBUT);
    COTEGRILLE = TAILLE * TAILLECASE;
    //this.setUndecorated(true); //Remove Title Bar AND EXIT BUTTON SO ADD ONE!!!!!
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true); //This is always on top 
    this.setResizable(false);
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int xsize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
    int ysize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight();
    this.setSize(xsize, ysize);

    Container1 = new JPanel();                          //Initialisation de la grille de Sudoku
    Container1.setLayout(null);
    Container1.setBounds((this.getWidth()/2)-(9*TAILLECASE/2),(this.getHeight()/2)-(9*TAILLECASE/2),COTEGRILLE,COTEGRILLE);
    Container1.setBackground(Color.white);


    for(int li = 0; li<TAILLE; li++){                       // remplissage de la grille
        for (int col = 0; col<TAILLE; col++){

            cases[li][col] = new JTextField(Integer.toString(NOMBRES_DEBUT[li][col]));
            cases[li][col].setBounds(li*TAILLECASE,col*TAILLECASE,TAILLECASE,TAILLECASE);
            cases[li][col].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
            cases[li][col].getDocument().addDocumentListener(new Ecouteur());           
            cases[li][col].getDocument().putProperty ("owner", cases[li][col]);
            Container1.add(cases[li][col]);

            if( li == 2 || li == 5){    
                if(col == 2 || col == 5){
                    Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1,1,4,4,new Color(0, 0, 0));
                    cases[li][col].setBorder(border);
                }else{      
                    Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1,1,1,4,new Color(0, 0, 0));
                    cases[li][col].setBorder(border);
                }
            }else if (col == 2 || col == 5){
                Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1,1,4,1,new Color(0, 0, 0));
                cases[li][col].setBorder(border);

            }else{
                Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1,1,1,1,new Color(0, 0, 0));
                cases[li][col].setBorder(border);
            }

            if(NOMBRES_DEBUT[li][col] == 0){            
                cases[li][col].setText("");
                cases[li][col].setBackground(new Color(204,204,204));
            }else{
                cases[li][col].setEditable( false);
            }

        }
    }

    int xButton = 200;
    int yButton = (int) ((xButton*3)/4);

    ImageIcon woodTemp = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Maxime\\Documents\\Perso\\Post-Bac\\INSA\\Projet Info\\unfinished-bamboo-flooring-ufc214.jpg");
    Image newImg = woodTemp.getImage();
    ImageIcon woodButton = new ImageIcon(newImg.getScaledInstance(xButton, yButton, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

    /*
    test.setIcon(woodButton);
    test.setBorder(null);
    test.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(xButton, yButton));
    test.setOpaque(false); 
    test.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    test.setBorderPainted(false);
    */
    test.setBounds((xsize/4)-100, (ysize/4)-75, xButton, yButton);
    test.addActionListener(this);

    containermain = new JPanel();
    containermain.setBounds(0,0, xsize, ysize);
    containermain.setOpaque(false);
    containermain.setLayout(null);

    FOND_ECRAN = new JLabel ();
    FOND_ECRAN.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    containermain.add(FOND_ECRAN);
    containermain.add(test);

    int x = FOND_ECRAN.getWidth();
    ImageIcon temp = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Maxime\\Documents\\Perso\\Post-Bac\\INSA\\Projet Info\\nature-1520704451453-7117.jpg");
    Image img = temp.getImage();
    Image dimg = img.getScaledInstance(FOND_ECRAN.getWidth(), FOND_ECRAN.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(dimg);
    FOND_ECRAN.setIcon(imageIcon);

    setContentPane(containermain);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    menu.add(item);
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    containermain.add(Container1);

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public class Ecouteur implements DocumentListener{

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        action(e);
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        action(e);
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
        //action(e);
    }

    public void action (DocumentEvent e){
        for(int i = 0; i<TAILLE; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<TAILLE; j++){
                if(e.getDocument().getProperty("owner") == cases[i][j]){
                    String s = cases[i][j].getText();       //Enlever tous les i,j, n et leur donner un nom
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(s);        // Remplace la string s en un nombre
                    if(n < 1 || n > 9){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(containermain, " entrez un nombre entre 1 et 9"); 
                    }else{
                        cases[i][j].setBackground(Color.white); 
                        GRILLE_MODIF[i][j] = n;
                        affichage(GRILLE_MODIF);
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
        //Verification if the grid is complete
    }
}

public void append ( String s){}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == b) {
        this.dispose();
    }else if(e.getSource() == test) {
        SudokuBackTrack sbt = new SudokuBackTrack(NOMBRES_DEBUT);
        GRILLE_FINALE = sbt.grille;
        for(int i = 0; i < TAILLE; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < TAILLE; j++) {
               cases[i][j].setText(Integer.toString(GRILLE_FINALE[i][j]));
            }
        }
    }
}

public void affichage(int[][] t) {
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<9; j++){
            System.out.print(t[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: *The problem is I have no idea where the two index are being swapped.* This is where you start [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I have shmosel, I've added loads of prints to see where it's happening and I still can't find it...

Comment: Print statements are not a practical debugging method. Use your IDE's debugger to step through the lines and watch the variables change.

Comment: Thanks, your method helped me notice part of the problem shmosel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your offending line is:

```
cases[li][col].setBounds(li*TAILLECASE,col*TAILLECASE,TAILLECASE,TAILLECASE);
```

To fix, change it to:

```
cases[li][col].setBounds(col*TAILLECASE,li*TAILLECASE,TAILLECASE,TAILLECASE);
```

setBounds parameters are setBounds(x, y, width, height).
li (the vertical line index) should correspond to y, and col should correspond to the x coordinate.

One coding practice I use when managing arrays like this in GUIs is to explicitly name my iteration variables x and y, so that I do not get confused.

Comment: Another thing you can do to save yourself confusion down the line is to use consistent ordering of variables. Your array is defined in the format [y index][x index]. You could consider changing the format to be [x index][y index] so that it corresponds to the order of parameters in most other functions.

Comment: Thank you so so much, I've been on this for 4 hours now and I can't see the code clearly anymore, I've just noticed the problem now. Probably time to call it a night, thanks again !

Comment: No problem! If you can, please vote my answer up. I've been trying to get my rep up so I can comment and what not.

Comment: I tried but I need a higher rep to visibly vote, sorry :(